# Make Checkbox drawable with layer-list

Tags: android, checkbox, drawable, layer-list

I am unable to understand layer-list behaviour and the padding given inside the shape tag. I want to draw a check box like this

[image: Required Image]

After trying a lot, what I've achieved so far is

[image]

Code for above drawable is :

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ed145b" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="-5dp"
            android:left="-5dp"
            android:right="-5dp"
            android:top="-5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="4px"
            android:color="#ed145b" />

        <size
            android:height="20dp"
            android:width="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Checbox is cutting from left side. And couldn't get any solution for it so far.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't being cut by the layout or another item in the layout instead?

Comment: I checked it twice but it wasn't the problem but the solution below solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ed145b" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="4px"
            android:color="#ed145b" />

        <size
            android:height="20dp"
            android:width="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Solved my problem by adding padding to the item not to the shape.